# How can we set required equals false using schema.path?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

I have schema/document having name and id as a field.

```
const newSchema: Schema = new Schema({
name:{
type:String,
required:true
},
id:{
type:String,
required:true
}
});
```

How can we define a method which sets required equals false for id field using schema.path?